# How do I create an Aurelia Plugin that's configurable?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm creating a new plugin based off the [Aurelia Skeleton Plugin](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-plugin). But I don't know how to make it configurable. I want users to set a property (an API path specifically) when they add my plugin. So that whenever they use the plugin it's configured how they need.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a second "callback" argument to your plugins `configure` method:

```js
configure(frameworkConfig, callback) {
```

2. Check whether this argument was passed in. If it was, invoke it with your "Configurer" class.

```js
const myPluginConfiguration = new MyPluginConfiguration();
if (callback instanceof Function) {
    callback(myPluginConfiguration);
}
```

3. Finally, apply the configuration:

```js
myPluginConfiguration.apply();
```

---

The application consuming your plugin would do something like this in their main.js

```js
...
.plugin('my-plugin', config => config.apiPath('https://api.foo.com/'))
...
```

---

And your plugin's configuration class might look something like this:

```js
export class MyPluginConfiguration {
  apiPath(path) {
    // do something with path
  }

  apply() {
    // any final configuration...
  }
}
```

Here's an official example: https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/src/aurelia-validation.ts#L53

Comment: How do you apply the changes in the apply method? I can't seem to get an instance of the plugin.

Comment: change the signature of `apply` to whatever you need. In the example I linked I think it's `apply(container)`.

Comment: I tried that, but when I reference container from frameworkConfig it's undefined.

Comment: what's undefined?
https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/0.12.1/src/aurelia-validation.ts#L67

Comment: frameworkConfig doesn't have a property called container when I run the Karma test in the plugin skeleton. I guess this doesn't work directly in the skeleton.

Comment: looks like it's a stub not the real thing: https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-plugin/blob/master/test/unit/configure.spec.js#L3